# Navbar a:hover won't change backgroundd color

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

Good day! So here's the thing, I have a previously been working with an HTML file that has a navbar. Unfortunately, I have made some changes and that resulted, in my navbar not changing background color and text color. It was previously able to change into a bright orange/gold color when the the texts on the navbar was hovered on. I don't know what happend, please help me. I'm somewhat new to this.

HTML FILE (Browser)
[image]

```css
body {
  background-image: url("assets/background.png");
  background-height: 100%;
  background-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#home {
  background-color: 009598;
  color: white;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: f78104;
  color: black;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("assets/grayUnderlay.png");
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img id="homeImg" src="assets/logo.png">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p id="name"><img id="mePic" src="assets/favicon.png">...</p>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you replace the screenshots with the actual code / code snippet, so we don't need to retype everything in order to help ?

Comment: You should add a code snippet, not screenshots. More than that, the CSS colors can't work without the hex mark (#) and you seem to be missing a couple of HTML ID attributes. Code might not work because you have no `#navbar` ID in your HTML, so no style applies.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `.navbar`. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: The question is tagged [bootstrap-5] but your code is based on the [bootstrap-3] navbar

Answer (score 1):

This should be the code you're looking for.

Overall feedback:

1. Make sure your HEX colors have the proper format *(they need to start with #)*.
2. Don't use ID's for styling
3. Make sure to streamline the way you write your classes/IDs, maybe stick to the naming convention of your current framework

```css
body {
  background-image: url("assets/background.png");
  background-color: aqua;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("assets/grayUnderlay.png");
  position: relative;
}

.home {
  background-color: #009598;
  color: white;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #f78104;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="" class="home-img">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p class="name"><img src="assets/favicon.png" alt="" class="me-pic">...</p>
  </div>
</nav>
```